# Is there a way to open an "extra" temporary workspace?

Tags: 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces, workspace-switcher

[Running Ubuntu 14.04, Unity]

So, I have workspaces enabled and all that jazz. I know one can set some option so that Ubuntu defaults to more than four workspaces—but that's not what I want.

Currently, I'd like a *fifth* workspace, but only temporarily (that is, I don't want it to be the default that five open. I just want it for today, and possibly w/e other day I need it).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I imagine you are using Unity (default Ubuntu flavor); better you specify this in your question, because this question is desktop-environment dependent. Using Ubuntu Gnome, for example, workspaces are dynamic --- created or destroyed on the fly. I hated it at first, now I really like it...

Comment: Do you have any particular way you would like to activate / deactivate the extra workspace?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Ideally, I'd like to press a hotkey, but it doesn't matter that much to me.

Comment: Good to see the question is still "alive". I posted my answer.

Comment: I ran into this answer / question from a while ago. Could you tell me how it ended? Did any of the answers work?

Answer (score 2):

The script below allows you to keep two different sets of worspaces. If you place the script under a shortcurt key, you can toggle between the two sets:

normal workspaces -

[image]

extended workspaces -

[image]

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file. In the head section, define the "normal" situation in rows / columns:

   ```
   normal = (2, 2)
   ```

   and the "extended" situation you'd like to see in rows / columns:

   ```
   extended = (2, 4)
   ```
2. Save the script as `manage_workspaces.py`. Test if it does want you want it to do by running the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/manage_workspaces.py
   ```

   When you run the command, the workspace setup should toggle between the two sets, and a message should appear in the notification area (see the pictures above)
3. If all works well, add the command to run the script to a shortcut key of your choice:
   Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts"
    
   Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/manage_workspaces.py
   ```

   The script:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3

   import subprocess

   # default situation rows / columns
   normal = (2, 2)
   # extended set of workspaces
   extended = (2, 4)
   # commands to read the current state
   key = "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/"
   read_hor = "dconf read "+key+"hsize"; read_vert = "dconf read "+key+"vsize"
   hor = int(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", read_hor]).decode("utf-8").strip())
   vert = int(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", read_vert]).decode("utf-8").strip())
   # take action, depending on current state
   if (hor,vert) == normal:        
       set_h = "dconf write "+key+"hsize "+str(extended[1])
       set_v = "dconf write "+key+"vsize "+str(extended[0])
       message = "notify-send 'set to extended workspaces: "+str(extended[0])+" x "+str(extended[1])+"'"
   else:
       set_h = "dconf write "+key+"hsize "+str(normal[1])
       set_v = "dconf write "+key+"hsize "+str(normal[0])
       message = "notify-send 'set to normal workspaces: "+str(normal[0])+" x "+str(normal[1])+"'"
   for item in (set_h, set_v, message):
       subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", item])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have a outdated PPA that might work but the workspace is not temporarily available. So to disable/enable you must go to the application.

PPA: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main